# How to store image files in Amazon S3 and Videos in Vimeo using Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, vimeo, django-storage

I want to store the image files in the S3 and the video files in the Vimeo in my django project. I am `S3Boto3Storage` of `Django-storage` as the storage backend. As Vimeo takes care of compression and content delivery for video files and it's cheap compared to S3, I want to use that for video files.

I thought of uploading the file to the Vimeo using the `upload_to` attribute in the `FileField` of django model, but I can't able to get the absolute path of the video file in the method.

here is my implementation of the `upload_to` method,

```
import vimeo


def vimeo_client():
    client = vimeo.VimeoClient(
        token=settings.VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        key=settings.VIMEO_CLIENT_ID,
        secret=settings.VIMEO_CLIENT_SECRET
    )
    return client

def get_media_path(instance, filename):
    new_filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), filename.split('.')[-1])
    if instance.type == 'image':
        file_path = 'posts/media/images/{filename}'.format(
            filename=new_filename)
    else:
        client = vimeo_client()
        file_path = client.upload(
            filename,
            data={
                'name': instance.title,
                'description': instance.description
            }
        )
    logger.info("File uploaded to: [{}]".format(file_path))
    return file_path
```

But it's giving me this error

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'videoplayback.mp4'

Or I could customise the `S3Boto3Storage` for my purpose. I would like to know what would be the better solution.

**Edit**
Here is the full stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
response = self._middleware_chain(request)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 139, in handle_uncaught_exception
return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/appcore/src/appcore/wsgi.py", line 24, in null_technical_500_response
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
response = self._get_response(request)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 551, in wrapper
return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 224, in inner
return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1508, in add_view
return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1408, in changeform_view
return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1448, in _changeform_view
self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 979, in save_model
obj.save()
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 808, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 838, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 924, in _save_table
result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 963, in _do_insert
using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1076, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1112, in execute_sql
for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1065, in as_sql
for obj in self.query.objs
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1014, in pre_save_val
return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 296, in pre_save
file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 93, in save
name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 327, in generate_filename
filename = self.upload_to(instance, filename)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/appcore/src/utils/common.py", line 50, in get_media_path
'description': instance.description
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vimeo/upload.py", line 49, in upload
filesize = self.__get_file_size(filename)
File "/Users/rohanroy/development/django/zappa/arete/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vimeo/upload.py", line 163, in __get_file_size
return os.path.getsize(filename)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 57, in getsize
return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'videoplayback.mp4'
```

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace; and the changes you made to settings.py for Boto?

Comment: i suggest use Official Python library for the Vimeo

Comment: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos

Comment: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.py

Comment: I am already using the official python library @Tegito123. The issue is the library could not find the absolute path of the video uploaded from admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimeo API's supports 3 types of video upload strategies which are discussed [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#understanding-upload-approaches). The `tus` approach assumes that the video file is in the local system. To upload video from the browser one need to use the `form-based uploads` approach which is not useful for an API only server. There is two option to tackle this,

> 1. Upload the video from the client-side to the API server using your own API endpoint and then use `vimeo.py` to upload it to the `Vimeo` and delete the actual video file from the server.
> 2. Use [`vimeo.js`](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js) to upload the video file from the client side and then store the returned `video_uri` in the backend.